# subsetting and assignment in R

Tags: r

I'm learning R using *Advanced R* by Hadley Wickham.
In the chapter subsetting and assignment, I didn't understand the following example:

```
x <- 1:5
x[c(1, 2)] <- 2:3
x
#> [1] 2 3 3 4 5
# The length of the LHS needs to match the RHS
```

Comment: You simply replaced the first two values in `x`(shown by `c(1, 2)`) with the vector `c(2, 3)` (shown as `2:3`).  Probably not the best example since the first two values are the same as the index

Comment: What's the problem? Did you want tor replace the first and second positions with the second and third elements: `x[c(1, 2)] <- x[2:3]`

Comment: I think *Advanced R* is a great book but if your struggling with this maybe you should start with some more introductory material.

Answer (score 3):

Can be broken down into

```
x <- 1:5
> x
# 1 2 3 4 5
```

`x[c(1, 2)]` means index position 1, 2 of `x` vector which currently has a value `1` and `2` is replaced now by `2` and `3` by the statement

```
x[c(1, 2)] <- 2:3
```

Hence, the final value of vector is

```
x
# 2 3 3 4 5
```